# Using min-width with overflow

Tags: css

With the following markup:

```
<div style="overflow: auto">
    <select multiple="true" style="min-width: 300px;">
        <option>a loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong string</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

min-width causes the select width to be 100% of the container, i.e it will NOT overflow. Removing the min-width, cases it to overflow (which is the desired behaviour, but i also want a minimum width so that the box looks decent even with no options).

How can this be achieved? The fact that min-width affects max-width disturbs me. Note that I'm only interested in a css-solution, avoiding javascript.

EDIT: To clarify, the styling should cause the following markup to render an empty box, that is 300px wide:

```
<div>
    <select multiple="true">
    </select>
</div>
```

And the following to render a box that is as wide as its container, with a scrollbar to allow viewing of the rest:

```
<div>
    <select multiple="true">
        <option>a loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong string</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I find your lack of faith disturbing

Comment: add width: 300px to your div element.

Comment: adding width to the div element still doesn't cause the select to overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Ive tried to find a solution, but it seems that css is pretty stubborn when it comes to setting the width for a select element once it has a defined min-width.

Ive made a simple workaround in JS/JQuery though, it seems to be working nice in my JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RHfm4/2/

```
var v = $("select");
  for(var i = 0; i < v.length; i++){
    if(parseInt($(v[i]).css("width")) < 300){
      $(v[i]).css("width", "300px");
  }
}​​​​​​​
```

This will get you the functionality you need, but it is only a workaround. Hope this is somewhat helpfull.

Comment: Technically works, but gets pretty ugly, especially since I will change the elements in the list with javascript, thus I would have to run the code every time a change occurs! In the end, I will probably use a different solution that does not involve min-width.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Its not an optimal solution. Hope you find a acceptable way to solve the problem, it was pretty tricky.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully it helps you...

```
<div style="min-width:300px; overflow-x: auto">
  <select multiple="true" style="width: auto;">
    <option>a loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong string</option>
    <option>a long string</option>
    <option>a long string</option>
    <option>a long string</option>                                    
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: min-width on the div achieves nothing, it has to be on the select.

Comment: Why you want width on "select", if this is already overflowed?

Comment: I don't, I want width on select if there are no options. I.e a min-width.